# Error for load the fixtures Symfony 2 [OutOfBoundsException] Reference to: (image) does not exist

Tags: symfony

I have a OneToOne relation between the Article entity and Image entity, the Article entity is the owner  , I created the  fixtures data files to load the database , I used the " faker " to format the type file, when I run the command:

```
$ app / console doctrine : fixtures : load
```

I get this error message :

```
:[OutOfBoundsException]                                                                                                                                                      
Reference to: (image) does not exist
```

in my fixtures files:
ns\NikahBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadArticleData.php:

```
<?php
namespace ns\NikahBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

use ns\NikahBundle\Entity\Article;


class LoadArticleData extends AbstractFixture implements    OrderedFixtureInterface
{
const MAX_NB_ARTICLES = 10;

public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{

    $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();
    for ($i = 0; $i < self::MAX_NB_ARTICLES; ++$i) {
        $article = new Article();
        $article->setAuteur($faker->text(250));
        $article->setTitre($faker->text(250));
        $article->setContenu($faker->text(250));
        $article->setDeleted($faker->boolean);

        $image = $this->getReference('image');
        $article->setImage($image);
        $manager->persist($article);
    }

    $manager->flush();
}
public function getOrder(){
    return 1;
}
}
```

in my  ns\NikahBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadImageData.php:

```
<?php
 namespace ns\NikahBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

use ns\NikahBundle\Entity\Image;


class LoadImageData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface

{
 const MAX_NB_IMAGES = 5;

public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();

    for ($i=0; $i<self::MAX_NB_IMAGES; ++$i){
        $image = new Image();
        $image->setUrl($faker->imageUrl($width = 640, $height = 480));
        $image->setAlt($faker->text);

        $manager->persist($image);

        $this->addReference('image', $image);

    }
        $manager->flush();
}

   public function getOrder(){
       return 2;
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, LoadImageData should be launch before LoadArticleData.

```
class LoadImageData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    / *** /

    public function getOrder(){
        return 1;
    } 
}
```

and

```
class LoadArticleData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{

    / *** /

    public function getOrder(){
       return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , but when i change the order , i have this message : [BadMethodCallException]
Reference to: (image) already exists, use method setReference in order to override it